Power BI Creating a Table based on "Best Available" Data from Other Tables
I want to setup a report that will present data to the end user using the "best available" data that we have. I plan to maintain 3 databases with identical structure in each of them.  There will be "Prelim Data", "Final Data Unverified" and then "Final Data Locked ".
I want to be able to report on best available data. So if there is "Final Data Locked" in a cell, use that, otherwise use "Final Data Unverified", otherwise "Prelim Data"
Firstly, I am able to create a new table and manually add columns with the below code, but is there an easier way to create the whole table without me writing code for every column? (There will have over 100 columns)
A = if(isblank(lookupvalue('Final Data Locked'[A],'Final Data Locked'[Test Data],'Data To Use Table'[Test Data])),if(isblank(lookupvalue('Final Data Unverified'[A],'Final Data Unverified'[Test Data],'Data To Use Table'[Test Data])),lookupvalue('Prelim Data'[A],'Prelim Data'[Test Data],'Data To Use Table'[Test Data]),lookupvalue('Final Data Unverified'[A],'Final Data Unverified'[Test Data],'Data To Use Table'[Test Data])),lookupvalue('Final Data Locked'[A],'Final Data Locked'[Test Data],'Data To Use Table'[Test Data]))

Secondly, and this is probably a nice to have only, it would be amazing if the user could toggle the report to exclude "Prelim Data" and/or "Final Data Unverified" so they only see the report with "Final Data Locked." Is there an easy way to achieve this?
I have done in the past through a selected value being used on measures, but since it is currently either through calculated columns or possibly calculate table, unsure if there is achievable?
Data Example

You can create a new table based on three available table and the output will be as below-

At first add a new custom column "Table Priority" to your 3 table as below-

Use value-
1 for table "Final Data Locked"
2 for table "Final Data Unvarified"
3 for table "Prelim Data"

And here is the Advance query for the new table-
let
    Append1 = let
    Source = Table.Combine({#"Prelim Data", #"Final Data Unvarified", #"Final Data Locked"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Source,{"Test Data", "Table Priority", "Sum of A", "Sum of B", "Sum of C", "Sum of D"}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Reordered Columns", {"Test Data", "Table Priority"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Test Data", Order.Ascending}, {"Attribute", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "min_priority", each if [Value] = "" or [Value] is null then null else [Table Priority]),
    #"table_1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Table Priority"}),
    #"table_2" = Table.Group(#"table_1", {"Test Data", "Attribute"}, {{"min_priority_new", each List.Min([min_priority]), type nullable number}}),

    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(
        table_1, {"Test Data","Attribute", "min_priority"}, 
        table_2, {"Test Data","Attribute", "min_priority_new"},
        "new_table", JoinKind.Inner
    )

in
    #"Merged Queries",
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Append1,{"new_table", "min_priority"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"

